# "IllegalStateException: No generator was provided" when using Jersey-Client on Glassfish 3 in Java EE 7 application

Tags: jax-rs, glassfish-3, jersey-2.0, java-ee-7, jersey-client

For a project I'm using Jersey-Client to interface with another project's REST interface.

I am using the following code:

```
    public boolean canLogin(String server, String username, String password) {
    Client client = null;
    try {
        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager

        client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
        HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(username, password);
        client.register(feature);
        Response resp = client.target(server + "/management").request().get();

        return resp.getStatus() == 400;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (client != null) {
            client.close();
        }
    }
}
```

When using it, I get the following exception in ex

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No generator was provided and there is no default generator registered
```

The code is being run on GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)

All of the dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>be.dkv</groupId>
        <artifactId>PasswordManagement-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Glassfish 3.x uses Jersey 1.x. You're trying to use Jersey 2.x. My guess is that's where the problem lies. Try to use Glassfish 4 and see what happens. Or change the Jersey version you're using. And just FYI, That glassfish uses EE 6 not 7

Comment: Using Glassfish 3.x is our only option right now, unfortunately. I'll try to move to Jersey 1.x. Thanks regardless.